# Slow message retrieval from SQS

Tags: java, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Given a Java AWS Lambda with the following code:

```
private static final String QUEUE_URL = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<ACCT_NUMBER>/<QUEUE_NAME>";
private static final AmazonSQS client = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().build();
private static final int MAX_SQS_MESSAGES = 10;
```

And:

```
private List<Message> getMessages() {
    return client.receiveMessage(new ReceiveMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(QUEUE_URL)
            .withMaxNumberOfMessages(MAX_SQS_MESSAGES).withWaitTimeSeconds(1)).getMessages();
}
```

I experience rather "long" SQS retrieval times (considering the specified 1 second base for long polling), as sample evidence from logs:

- Got 3 SQS msgs: 1985ms
- Got 8 SQS msgs: 1887ms
- Got 9 SQS msgs: 2438ms
- Got 5 SQS msgs: 1748ms

Are those time between normal operation or, could I be doing something wrong or improve something?

Maven dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.488</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Those are indeed *very* long delays, and something is wrong.** With a non-empty queue, you should be able to get typical reads in the 5-500ms range (lower with more messages available). Even if your queue is empty, the request times should be topping out around a maximum of 1s based on your usage of `withWaitTimeSeconds` in the request.

There are a number of steps you can take to  narrow down the problem:

1. Make sure the queue and the lambda are in the same region - I mention this first as I've seen so many latency issues caused by cross-region calls in AWS.
2. Make sure you have accurate request metrics. I don't see how you are measuring the metrics timing in your code, but I do see how you're constructing your client.

   - Create an implementation of [`RequestHandler2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/handlers/RequestHandler2.html) that implements `afterError` and `afterResponse`, and examines the details of [`request.getAWSRequestMetrics()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/Request.html#getAWSRequestMetrics--)
   - Add that request handler to the client via [`clientBuilder.withRequestHandlers(RequestHandler2... handlers)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#withRequestHandlers-com.amazonaws.handlers.RequestHandler2...-)
   - This will give you accurate details of how the request is spending its time, and perhaps reveal some obvious problems, and may also point to a problem outside of the call to SQS.
3. Make sure you are reusing your client (and not creating a fresh one each time) - consider logging each time your client is created. Under the hood of the client there's a lot of setup, and if it's using a fresh client every time, there might be a lot of time wasted there.

Comment: Regarding #3: Client is static final and lambda is run every 2 mins, so I guess it's getting reused, but I'll set logging on that. And I'm measuring just a wrapper above the getMessages, not the client instantiation per-se

Comment: Logging shows that client IS being reused, so that option is being ruled out. Deleted the "long polling" associated to the 1 sec wait and overall behaviour is much better. Perhaps is related to our use case where the queue has just about 5-10 msgs per loop. I'll keep it working and monitoring this way and see how it behaves on a longer time frame